# In-App Purchase Localized Price

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm testing my In-App Purchases (consumable) and I'm facing price difference between what is in `iTunes`, what's listed on my `SKRequest` and what's shown on `alert purchase confirmation`. I'm connected using a french app store user.

This is my iTunes configuration, price is **1,99** USD:
[image]

This is my request value:
[image]

Until here I can understand as Apple has different price policy for different regions and according to price list that is the correct conversion **1,99 USD = 2,29 €**.

The problem is, once I tap **I want it**, I start the purchase process and a standard alert is shown with product information to confirm the purchase:
[image]

Then the prices raises to **2,99 €** !!

To fill my In-App table I'm getting the property :

```
product.priceLocale
```

Can anyone explains me why ?

Comment: Did you solve it? Did you try `product.localizedPrice`?

Comment: It is a sandbox bug. I’ll post the answer. Thanks to remind me